# div tag not acting right

Tags: html, stylesheet

I'm trying to make a website looking like the example at "Using  tag elements" from here http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_layout.asp but my `<div>` doesn't show next to the menu bar, and I can't see why. my code is here:

```
< head>  
  < style>  
div, p {  
    margin: 0px;  
    padding: 0px;  
}  
< /style>  
< /head>  
< body>  
< a href="#" onclick="window.print();return false;">Udskriv< /a>  
< div id="container" style="width:500px">  
< div id="menu" style="background-color:red;height:100px;width:10%;float;left;">
< a href="forside.html">Forside</a><br>
< a href="kalender.html">Kalender</a><br>
< a href="hvem_er_vi.html">Hvem er vi</a><br>
< a href="nyheder.html">Nyheder</a><br>
< a href="meetings.html">Møder</a><br>
< a href="aktiviteter.html">Aktiviteter</a><br>
< a href="presse.html">Presse</a><br>
< a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a><br>
< a href="links.html">Links</a>
< /div>
< div id="content" style="height:200px;width:200px;float;left;">text1< /div>  
< p>text2< /p>  
< /div>  
< /body>
```

I can't see why my div-tag with text1 appears below menu bar instead of right of it, it has the required space (and more), including it had no margin or padding

Comment: Tip: http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: Because your menu is not floated as you think, because of the syntax error in your inline CSS – `float;left;` – a `:` instead of a `;` is needed here.

Comment: Tip #2: Remove the useless space when typing a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove height defiend for menu bar to set dynamic height relative to content and so

```
<div id="menu" style="background-color:red;float:left;width:10%">
```

you missed close `<a tags`

I have edited your code :

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.print();return false;">Udskriv</a>

<div id="container" style="width:100%">
    <div id="menu" style="background-color:red;float:left;width:10%"> 
        <a href="forside.html">Forside</a>
        <a href="kalender.html">Kalender</a>
        <a href="hvem_er_vi.html">Hvem er vi</a>
        <a href="nyheder.html">Nyheder</a>
        <a href="meetings.html">Møder</a>
        <a href="aktiviteter.html">Aktiviteter</a>
        <a href="presse.html">Presse</a>
        <a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a>
        <a href="links.html">Links </a>
    </div> 
    <div id="content" style="height:200px;width:200px;float:left;">text1</div>
    <p>text2</p>
</div>
```

note that `float;right` is not correct 
right syntax of float is : `float:right`